# How to pass multiple commands in Kubernetes container?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, debian

I'm trying to deploy a container in Kubernetes and at the same time copy a file from one of the persistent volumes to specific directory. The problem is that if i run the command without delay it will try to copy the file before mounting the persistent volume.
I'd like to help me with the syntax to delay the copy command few seconds until the persistent volume is mounted.

I tried to type the command field like that but the container crashes while deploying the pod.

```
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: andreask81/syspass:latest
        name: syspass-app
        command: ["/bin/bash"]
        args: ["sleep 30", "cp /var/www/html/sysPass/config/backup/config.xml /var/www/html/sysPass/config/config.xml"]
```

And this one also did not work and caused the pod to crash right after container creation.
`command: ["/bin/bash","-c","sleep 10 && cp /var/www/html/sysPass/config/backup/config.xml /var/www/html/sysPass/config/config.xml"]`

In the meanwhile, when I run the following command inside similar container directly in the shell it works.
`/bin/bash -c "sleep 1" && cp /var/www/html/sysPass/config/backup/config.xml /var/www/html/sysPass/config/config.xml`

### Any idea how can I format the "**command:**" field in the YAML file to make this work?

***** Update 1 *****
I've updated the container to include a script that does the required steps as the following

```
    #!/bin/bash
    
    while [ ! -f /var/www/html/sysPass/config/backup/config.xml ]; do
        sleep 10;
    done
    
    cp /var/www/html/sysPass/config/backup/config.xml /var/www/html/sysPass/config/config.xml
    chown www-data:www-data /var/www/html/sysPass/config/config.xml
    chmod 664 /var/www/html/sysPass/config/config.xml
```

The pod fails with the following errors:

```
/tmp/script.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
/tmp/script.sh: line 10: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I also tried to manually run the script from command line but it failed with the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest file, you didn’t add **-c** to the command value or at the beginning of your args. Any reason for this? Do add it and give it another go:

```yaml
spec:
  containers:
  - image: andreask81/syspass:latest
    name: syspass-app
    command: ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
    args: ["sleep 30 && cp /var/www/html/sysPass/config/backup/config.xml /var/www/html/sysPass/config/config.xml"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could update your container to contain a script that performs this work for you before starting the main app with something like:

#### script.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while [ ! -f /path/to/some/file ]; do
    sleep 3;
done
```

Make it executable.

```
chmod u+x script.sh
```

Add the script to your docker image and set it as the first thing to run in the ENTRYPOINT - this defers the file checking until run-time.

```
FROM some-image:0.0.1
....
COPY script.sh /tmp/script.sh
ENTRYPOINT /bin/bash /tmp/script.sh && <THE_REST_OF_YOUR_COMMAND_HERE_FOR_MAIN_APPLICATION>
```

Test your new image runs locally with `docker run`

Comment: Thanks for your insight. I've followed your tip but since the script will not be always required for all use cases for that docker image, I don't want to start it from ENTRYPOINT, instead I'd like to call it from K8s yaml file as "J Muniz" mentioned on the below post.

The issue I have is that whenever I pass the script in Command field the container creation fails on the pod. I tried the below syntax variations.
command: ["sh", "-c", "/tmp/script.sh"], command: ["/tmp/script.sh"] and command: ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/tmp/script.sh"].

Comment: In that case I'd also add a reference in the script that checks whether an environment variable is true and only runs the custom script (from a parent script) if the environment variable is TRUE/Present. The advantage of a custom image is you can define the behaviour of its startup as you wish. Using the ENTRYPOINT to run the script allows you to defer a decision until run-time

Comment: In response to your comment about wanting to use an inline specification: Add `set -x` to your script to enable debug output from the bash script. Also review use of `init_container` for running this script vs the main application. If its a job, run it as such. You can review the logged output using `kubectl logs [pod_id [container]]`. It also helps to add exit codes: `command || exit 10;` for each line of functionality you want to work, otherwise it can appear to have run successfully since execution continues, but in reality it failed almost silently giving you false beliefs

Comment: I logged into the pod and attempted to run the command manually but it failed as I just shared on the latest post update.

Comment: did you try adding the "-c" arg just after "/bin/bash" for the command?

Answer (score -1):

You also could add a bash script with commands you need and call it on yaml command value.

Keep it clean :)